# Nokogiri and Xpath query

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have this Xpath query inside a loop,

```
//div[@class='listing_content'][#{i}]/div/div/h3/a/text()
```

I want to process each node individually

The problem it gives the correct nodes, but all of them at once at once.

Also when `i > 1`, it returns nothing at all?

```
for i in (1...30)
  name = page.xpath("//div[@class='listing_content'][#{i}]/div/div/h3/a/text()")
  puts "this is name"
  puts name

  #Get Business phone
  phone = page.xpath("//div[@class='listing_content'][#{i}]//span[@class='business-phone phone']/text()")
  puts "this is phone"
  puts phone

  #Get Business website(if any)
  puts "this is website"
  website = page.xpath("//div[@class='listing_content'][#{i}]//li[@class='website-feature']//@href")
  puts website
end
```

Comment: Could you post the markup you're working with?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance what's markup?

Comment: Hint: What does XML stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also when i > 1, it returns nothing at all?

This is the second most FAQ in XPath:

**Use**:

```
(//div[@class='listing_content'])[#{i}]/div/div/h3/a/text()
```

**The cause of the observed behavior is** that in XPath the `[]` has higher precedence (priority) than the `//` pseudo-operator.

So, in your original expression you specify that every `div[@class='listing_content']` element that is the `i`-th child of its parent should be selected.

However, in the XML document you are working with, every `div[@class='listing_content']`  happens to be the first (and only) child of its parent -- therefore if `i > 1` then nothing is selected.

As in any other language, in order to override the default priority, we must use brackets.

Comment: Is there a typo? it doesn't compile  if I add the parenthese in between the brackets.

Comment: @Mtl-z Mark:   Nope, I ran this successfully: `(//div[@class='listing_content'])[1]/div/div/h3/a/text()`

Comment: Ah allright I miscopy/pasted. Thanks a lot, it's working and I understand my mistake now.

Comment: @Mtl-zMark: I am glad this answer was useful to you. Could you, please, *accept* the answer by clicking on the check-mark next to it?